# Get the default value of a property of an abstract class

Tags: c#, properties, abstract-class, default-value, getter

Is there a way in C# to access the default value of a non-`static`, non-`const` property that is defined in an abstract class?

For example, given:

```cs
public abstract class SomeClass
{
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; } = 99;
}
```

I would like something similar to the following to return "**`99`**":

```cs
default(SomeClass.SomeProperty);
```

I know that the `default()` operator doesn't work like this and the above results in compiler error. What the `default()` operator can do is return the default value for `SomeClass`, which naturally is `null` for reference types, therefore:

```cs
default(Test).SomeProperty;
```

can be compiled but rightly throws a `NullReferenceException`.

**Note some assumptions for the context of this question:**

- the abstract class definition is not *easily* modifiable by me. It sits in an external library, to which I can propose changes, but it takes a long process of review/justification to apply such changes. This is why I would much favour solutions that do not require its modification.
  I still appreciate suggestions that could work by modifying it. I
  have already considered using an Attribute to store the default value and fetching it via Reflection.
- Please consider that there is no available concrete implementation of the abstract class.

*I already imagine that the answer to the main question is "no". However, it would be great to get insights from experts as per whether a feature for this could be (or has been) considered for implementation in C#, or if there are intrinsic language limitations that would prevent it from working, or simply it would have too scarce demand to justify an implementation.*

Comment: Have you considered creating a constant or static property, then initialising `SomeProperty` to that?

Comment: So how else would it be initialised then?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay The property cannot be a compile time constant or static. Thanks for highlighting that, I'll add this restriction to the question text. The point of the question is exactly that: to be able to access the default value (as written in the code) for the abstract class property. I know this is unusual, hence my post.

Comment: I'm not referring to the property, but the value. For example: `public abstract class SomeClass { public const int Default = 99; public int SomeProperty { get; set; } = Default; }`. If you could do that, then you could obtain the value of `SomeClass.Default`.

Comment: Why do you need the default value? And is there a specific reason you don't want or can't just apply a [`[DefaultValue(99)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute) attribute to the property? The attribute can be read easily by reflection. This is normally used by text-based serializers so they can omit serializing the property if its value is the same as the default value.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg thanks for the questions, I'll clarify in the answer text. In brief, the abstract class definition is not _easily_ modifiable by me (it sits in an external library on which I have to suggest changes and it takes a long time to review/accept them), but I would still like to get its default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing this `= 99` would require either:

1. using a Roslyn analyzer and inspecting the source at build-time
2. reading the IL of the constructor body *at runtime*, and interpreting the opcodes

The first option is probably easier; you can see an example of this in [protobuf-net.BuildTools](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/main/src/protobuf-net.BuildTools/Internal/DataContractContext.cs#L498), which checks for this usage, and raises a flag if there is not a matching `[DefaultValue(...)]`; a `[DefaultValue(...)]` is trivial to inspect at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the value to a constant:

```
public abstract class SomeClass
{
    public const int SomePropertyDefault = 99;
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; } = SomePropertyDefault;
}
```

Then you can access it as `SomeClass.SomePropertyDefault`.

If for some reason you can't then you can create your own derived class and instantiate it:

```
public class TestChild : SomeClass
{
}
```

and just use it - `var defaultVal = new TestChild().SomeProperty;`.

Other than that there is not much "easy" options without changing the code since the default value is compiled into part of the constructor invocation. From [decompilation @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAEBDARgZ2ACdsBjYTeTAZQHsBbAUwGEJt99UBvVTPyrGAB2FOkwAKRWgAdGRYAE9MXTAHNGwANyZ8G7QF9MAXkwBOU5tT7UQA):

```
.method family hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
    instance void .ctor () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2061
    // Code size 15 (0xf)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.s 99 // 99
    IL_0003: stfld int32 SomeClass::'<SomeProperty>k__BackingField' // assign 99 to backing field
    IL_0008: ldarg.0
    IL_0009: call instance void [System.Runtime]System.Object::.ctor()
    IL_000e: ret
} // end of method SomeClass::.ctor
```